# Chrome javascript image to canvas causes empty image

Tags: javascript

Converting image to the canvas with canvas.drawImage fails(but not throws err), the canvas looks transparent empty image

It doesn't happen for all image files I could not figure out which property of the image causes this but I uploaded an example photo with this issue

I started having this problem with chrome v83-v84
firefox works fine.

**I want to upload a specified photo (its inside fiddle) and want to make canvas and draw canvas from the uploaded image and  display it on chrome (chrome version should bigger or equal v85)**

```
function testimg(src) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        document.querySelector('#test').appendChild(img)
    }

    $('#file').on('change', fileAdded)

    function fileAdded(event) {

        var reader = new FileReader;

        reader.onload = function () {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = reader.result;
            image.onload = function () {
                document.querySelector('#test').appendChild(this)
                var imgToSend = processImg(this, this.width, this.height);
                testimg(imgToSend)
            };
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(event.currentTarget.files[0]);

    }

    function processImg(image, srcWidth, srcHeight) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = srcWidth;
        canvas.height = srcHeight;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        ctx.fill();

        return canvas.toDataURL();
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/msacar/2Lgmc85t/24/

Comment: It works on my machine. Might be related to a security mechanism preventing canvases to draw cross origin images https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: Which version of chrome you are using ?

Comment: it was about chrome versions